# Unexpected behavior - Background location capture using fused location provider

Tags: android, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to use fused location provider to capture location in background every **half an hour** with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. To achieve this, I have used PendingIntent with BroadcastReceiver and requesting for a location update every thirty minutes. Open questions:-

1. Even though the documentation says setInterval(long duration) in **inexact** in nature, I am **not getting location updates at all for several hours** at times. In fact, it looks like it has stopped getting location updates completely sometimes.

2. Even though **GPS is ON all the time and in movement**, at times I get the **location as NULL** which is worrisome.

Above issues makes the location update logic in background not very reliable. I can use Alarm manager to wake every half hour and request for a location update but this looks an overhead, further this also may not guarantee the location update received will not be NULL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: there is never a guarantee that a location will be returned to you so you always have to handle a null location

Comment: Can we somehow ensure that a location update is triggered in around half an hour? unlike usual behavior where it is not triggered for hours/days some times? I know this will not be optimum from System's perspective but is there is any API that supports such behavior?

Comment: sure dont use `setInexactRepeating` and use `setExact`

Comment: There are no apis like setInexactRepeating or setExact. The api exposed is setInterval in LocationRequest class. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I thought you were using `AlarmManager`? AlarmManager is the only way to guarantee your location service is fired at the correct time

Comment: I haven't used it yet assuming that request for location updates every 30 minutes should be nice to use, when it is meant to be used like that. A deviation of 5-10 minutes for a capture every 30 minutes should be acceptable, but as I said, at several occasions update do not trigger at all making it unreliable. Knowing that AlarmManager will be an overhead I need to switch to that I guess.

Comment: What does your Location Request code look like?

Comment: hey..sorry for late response. I am using below post for this,https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/background-location-updates-on-android